# How to initialize and show meta tags in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

In pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @page = Page.find_by(url: params[:url])
    @meta = { title: @page.title, description: @page.description, keywords: @page.keywords }
  end
end
```

In layout I use such a way to show meta title of a page:

```
<title><%= @meta[:title] %></title>
```

But when I go other page, for example root page ("/") I have an error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Because for this page @meta is not initialized.

So I think I have to initialize @meta[:title] with a default value. Where in app should I put this code?

And one more. I want to wrap assigning @meta to a helper method. Where should I define it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in your `application_controller`, with a before_filter:

```
before_filter :initialize_metas

def initialize_metas
    @meta = { title: 'default_title', description: 'default_description', keywords: 'default_keywords' }
end
```

Then in your controllers than inherit from `application_controller` you can override it:

```
@meta = { title: @page.title, description: @page.description, keywords: @page.keywords }
```

or just override/add the keys you need:

```
@meta[:title] = 'another_title'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it is a bad idea to prepare some view-related data in a controller. Maybe, it would be better to provide some kind of presenter for your @post object.

Comment: I have to agree with you, my answer can also be the fastest, but this doesn't means it is also the best. Maybe using an Helper could be a better approach. Try to propose something and maybe you'll get the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this as Class variable

User @@meta in ApplicationController

@@ creates a class variable that you can use in all the project because all inherit from ApplicationController

Comment: Yeah, if OP wants the same meta tags on every page. This solution is so wrong.

Comment: OP ask about get meta in root as example, the only method of get a variable in root and in especific view controller is have a global variable

Comment: 1. No, it's not the only method. 2. It isn't even global variable!

Comment: Tell me please another method to do that withou passing as parameters I really want to know. Sorry a class variable that inherit in all Controllers

Comment: app-wide `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` like in iMacTia's answer? You really don't know this way?

Comment: Yes I knew but I didn't remmber thanx :)